# Sorting static multi dimentional array with custom compare function

Tags: c++, stl, sorting

There are examples of sorting vectors or dynamically allocated arrays but I couldn't find any help regarding static arrays. Let's say I have an array

```
int array[10][10];
```

and a compare function,

```
bool compare(const int (*a)[10], const int (*b)[10]);
```

When I call it like this,

```
std::sort(array, array + 10, compare);
```

I have compilation errors: `error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'const int (*)[10]' in argument passing`

I tried many ways, casting array to `(void**)` in sort function but then I have segmentation fault. My problem is using arrays as function parameters I guess but I couldn't figure out how to use this std::sort. Otherwise, I will have to write my own sort function.

Comment: You do realise that your comparison function takes two function pointers, don't you?

Comment: As cdecl states: "declare a as pointer to array 10 of int" It is pointer to arrays of int, size 10.

Comment: Can you quote the source for this, please? A pointer to an array of 10 ints should be const int *a[10], not const int (*a)[10].

Comment: it is from [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*a%29[10]). Actually it didn't matter when I declared arrays as you said. I still have errors like `error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'const int**' in argument passing`

Comment: @TimoGeusch `const int *a[10]` is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array.

Comment: @sftrabbit, good point, got that wrong.

Comment: why not make it a vector of vectors .. lets use the stl .. it's not c :p

Comment: I know but my program should be superfast. I create this array during execution all the time, so using static array will be faster at this point. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `std::sort` is called on a container of elements of type `T`, the comparison function needs to receive arguments of type `T` or `const T&`. In this case, you have a 2-dimensional array, so the type of elements is a 1-dimensional array `int[10]`. Since 1-dimensional arrays decay to pointers, `compare` can be:

```
bool compare(int a[10], int b[10]);
```

or equivalently:

```
bool compare(int *a, int *b);
```

This will fix the error you got, but your code still won't work: `std::sort` needs the container elements to be assignable (or movable in C++11), but arrays are not assignable.

You can use `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` instead as people have suggested. Note that your fear of performance problems is misguided: Even if sorting a two-dimensional array was possible, it would involve a lot of copying of one-dimensional arrays which would take a long time. Swapping vectors, on the other hand, is done by simply swapping pointers which is faster. In general, you should not make assumptions about performance if you haven't tested it first.

Comment: You're right about copying the contents of array while sorting, thank you reminding that! I guess I should switch to STL containers. I think I should give the answer to @Dietmar since he answered same answer as yours, a minute before. Thanks again!

Comment: @HalilKaskavalci: Do you realize that the contents of `std::array`s will also have to be copied, unlike vectors? I'm asking because of your comment on the other answer. BTW it was actually my answer which was earlier, but that doesn't matter - you should accept whatever answer is best :)

Comment: I thaught they can work as pointers, like vectors. I focused on fixed size containers since my contents does not change in size during execution. Then I think I will have no choice but using vectors. About answer, I didn't know it was your answer, sorry about that. Since you pointed the performance issues, I will try to choose your answer now then :). edit: can you please elaborate on why `std::array` contents needs to be copied? If it is `std::array< std::array<int, 10>, 10>` would that avoid copying?

Comment: @HalilKaskavalci please see my edited answer below - I'm not sure if it's the same as what you're doing, but it uses vectors and sorts on the sum of each row of data. -- The cool thing is, it uses async to calculate the sum of each row before doing the sort. According to the docs, the first call of future.get() will run the sum operation in the main thread, then subsequent calls will choose whether or not to spawn a new thread, taking advantage of multicore powers as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I say, if we're gonna use the STL and C++ .. lets write it in a modern style and really use the STL.

My attempt at the problem using modern c++11:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::vector<int> ArrayInt;
typedef std::vector< std::vector<int> > ArrayData;

bool compare(const ArrayInt& a, const ArrayInt& b) {
    std::cout << &(a) << ' ' << &(b) << std::endl;
    int sumA = std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);
    int sumB = std::accumulate(b.begin(), b.end(), 0);
    return sumA < sumB;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ArrayData array = {
        {1,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3},
        {13,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3},
        {10,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3},
        {1,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3},
        {16,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3},
        {1,2,400,0,3,7,6,8,3,3},
        {1,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3},
        {120,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3},
        {1,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3},
        {1,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3}
    };
    std::sort(array.begin(), array.end(), compare);
    for (auto row : array) {
        for (int num : row)
            std::cout << num << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It uses accumulate to sum each sub array, and sorts on the sum .. it's super inefficient because it has to sum the same row multiple times .. but it's just there to show off a custom compare function.

---

As an exercise, I wrote this version that uses async to distribute the summing part over any available cores to do the summing, before the sort. I'm sorry it's getting a bit off topic. I hope it's still useful to some people:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <future>

typedef std::vector<int> IntRow;
typedef std::pair<int, IntRow> DataRow;
typedef std::vector<DataRow> DataTable;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Holds the sum of each row, plus the data itself
    DataTable array = {
        {0, {1,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3}},
        {0, {13,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3}},
        {0, {10,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3}},
        {0, {1,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3}},
        {0, {16,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3}},
        {0, {1,2,400,0,3,7,6,8,3,3}},
        {0, {1,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3}},
        {0, {120,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3}},
        {0, {1,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3}},
        {0, {1,2,4,0,3,7,6,8,3,3}}
    };
    // Make use of multiple cores if it's efficient enough
    // get the sum of each data row
    std::vector<std::future<int>> sums(array.size());
    auto next = sums.begin();
    for (auto& row : array)
        *next++ = std::async([](const IntRow& row) { return std::accumulate(row.begin(), row.end(), 0); }, row.second);
    // Get the results
    auto nextRow = array.begin();
    for (auto& sum: sums)
        (*nextRow++).first = sum.get();
    // Sort it 
    std::sort(array.begin(), array.end(),
              [](const DataRow& a, const DataRow& b) { return a.first < b.first; });
    // Print it
    for (auto row : array) {
        for (int num : row.second)
            std::cout << num << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It needs to be compiled with pthread library or similar:

`g++ -O6 sort.cpp --std=c++11 -g -lpthread`

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however performance is a higher concern for my case. I use genetic algorithms and my program executes for 10-15 minutes for result. I have to do everything to reduce this time. If I create dynamically vectors which have slower rate because of size checking, execution time will be even longer. That is why I despereatly try to make it work like old C style. About function pointers, as I mentioned, declaring `const int *a[10]` didn't help either. I still have errors in sort function. Again, thank you for the answer.

Comment: The compare function defined above does not take function pointers, it takes pointers to `int[10]`.

Comment: Thanks - I removed that line from my answer .. I should have looked twice :)

Answer (score 1):

The comparison function doesn't get an iterator to the element passed but the dereferenced iterator, i.e., the value type. Thus, your comparison function would need to be declared as like the one below:

```
bool compare(int (&a0)[10], int (&a1)[10]);
```

You can verify that you can actually call it with array iterators:

```
compare(*(std::begin(array) + 0), *(std::begin(array) + 1));
```

However, this won't make it possible to sort you arrays: built-in arrays are not copy-assignable. The easiest way to sort statically sized arrays (where the outer dimension flexible) is to use `std::array<T, N>`:

```
std::array<int, 10> array[10];
std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array));
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding std::array. I will focus on that now.